# gnuplot invalid command when running a script

Tags: gnuplot

I simply want to run a script with gnuplot. I am using gnuplot in windows. So on gnuplot command line I type this

```
gnuplot histo.gp
```

However I get invalid command error like this

```
gnuplot> gnuplot histo.gp
         ^
         invalid command
```

How can I run a script in gnuplot for windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
gnuplot> load histo.gp
```

from the gnuplot command line.  If you want to run the script directly from the Windows command line, you should be able to run

```
# gnuplot.exe histo.gp
```

(Or similar, I don't use Windows.)